# How to list page translations next to the original in the same row?

Tags: views, 8, i18n-l10n

D8's multilingual features are way above average compared to other major competing solutions, but I'm still missing one feature, or I don't know about it being implemented in D8.

When I create transations of the same page, I see them on individual rows, one row per translation like this:

[image]

If you have more languages, let's say 5, it's not good for clarity to have it like this. It would be much more clear if it would be possible to display the page (original) in one row and to list all the available translations of the given page on the same row, like this:

[image]

Being able to do this in D8 would be a great benefit. Is this possible in D8?

Comment: It's just one of the many things it does, but TMGMT offers an overview that looks similar to that https://www.drupal.org/project/tmgmt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Translation Management Tool](https://www.drupal.org/project/tmgmt), considered as the successor of the  [Translation Overview](https://www.drupal.org/project/translation_overview) module, and "the" module to move forward with in D8 also. From its project page:

> ... provides a tool set for translating content from different sources. The translation can be done by people or translation services of all kinds. It builds on and uses existing language tools and data structures in Drupal and can be used in automated workflow scenarios.
>
> This module does not make i18n or any other language module for Drupal obsolete. It does only facilitate the translation process.

[One of its community pages](https://www.drupal.org/node/1490130) also contains some related screenprints, such as this one:

[image]

#### Plan B

Another possible approach that might be worth experimenting with, is to try to tune the View itself, by using "rewrite results" for each of the values in the columns with "Czech", "English", etc. And use these values to rewrite them to shown an image (like "Czech.jpg", "English.jpg", etc) with an "**Edit**" link below it. For the "**Add**"-equivalent you'd have to check what value you get for a 3rd language if you don't have a translation yet: if you do get something for that also, you could using a similar rewrite result, but then with an "Add" link.

Comment: I don't get it. I tried TMGMT just now, but from what it seems, it serves a different purpose compared to what I'm looking for. I basically just need something like a "tuned view", I don't need to solve the translation-related workflow. It's good that TMGMT can display pages like this http://imgur.com/Okn88SB in the Translation Jobs Overview, but I haven't been able to achieve the same thing by adjusting the usual view for listing content :-(

Comment: In fact, this image https://dev.acquia.com/sites/default/files/captura_de_pantalla_2015-12-22_a_las_17.30.27.png demonstrates perfectly what I'm trying to achieve (the language codes don't have to be in background-colored boxes, it would be even enough just as plain text). Is that possible in Drupal 8?

Comment: anybody, please? :)

Comment: @Ondrej: About the only other possible approach that I can think of and might be worth experimenting with, is to try to tuning the View itself, by using "rewrite results" for each of the values in the columns with "Czech", "English", etc. And use these values to rewrite them to shown an image (like "Czech.jpg", "English.jpg", etc) with an "edit" link below it. Extra question (for the "add"-equivalent): what value do you get for a 3rd language if you don't have a translation yet? Can you update you 1st picture to show that also?